# Numerical Integration - taking too long

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

recently I have been trying to calculate the following numerical integral

\begin{equation}
\frac{4 t}{\text{DD}}\frac{1}{2 \pi } \int_{0}^{\infty} dx \int_{0}^{\infty} d\epsilon \frac{\left(\frac{\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{x}\right)^2 \left(\left(\epsilon ^3 \exp (-2 \epsilon )\right) \left(\frac{\text{DD} t}{d^2}\right)^2\right)}{\left(\text{DD} x^2\right) \left(\frac{\epsilon ^4 \left(\frac{\text{DD} t}{d^2}\right)^2}{x^2}+1\right)}.
\end{equation}

which in Mathematica reads

```
exponent[(t_)?NumericQ, (DD_)?NumericQ, (d_)?NumericQ] := ((4*t)/DD)*(1/(2*Pi))*NIntegrate[(Sin[x/2]/x)^2*(((t*(DD/d^2))^2/(DD*x^2))*((\[Epsilon]^3*Exp[-2*\[Epsilon]])/(1 + ((DD/d^2)*t)^2*(\[Epsilon]^4/x^2)))), {x, zero, inf}, {\[Epsilon], zero, inf}]
```

Unfortunately, when I plot something like

```
plotexact = LogLogPlot[{exponent[1, 1, d], exponent[.1, 1, d], exponent[10, 1, d]}, {d, 10^-3, 10^3}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotPoints -> 10]
```

The Mathematica does not give me any plot after hours. I have tried to change the integral do main from $10^{-n}$ to $10^n$ with $n\approx5$ but that did not help at all. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integral just takes a while, particularly for small values of $d$.  For example, for $t = 1$, $DD = 1$, and $d = 10^{-3}$, my computer (which is admittedly not terribly fast) takes about 25 seconds to evaluate `exponent`.  And by default, Mathematica will sample the curve many, many times to ensure that it has captured all of the nuances of the graph.

You can force `LogLogPlot` to create a "cruder" graph by using the `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` options.  `PlotPoints` is the number of points that Mathematica samples the curve at initially;  `MaxRecursion` is the maximum number of times that Mathematica will sub-divide this initial graph to capture more variation in the curve.  The smaller both numbers are, the less sampling Mathematica will do, and the faster it will output a graph.

For example, the command

```
LogLogPlot[exponent[1, 1, d], {d, 10^-3, 10^3},
           PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> All]
```

returns the following graph after about 5–10 minutes on my computer:

[image]

(The `Mesh -> All` option shows you where Mathematica actually evaluated the function;  you can see that it is just linearly interpolating between these points.)